# Flutter custom showSearch without the appBar

Tags: flutter

I'm looking to create a search field (which calls an API to build suggestions) and I would love to use the ShowSearch class (to use all the functions already implemented in Flutter, delegates, etc...), but I do not want it to appear in an AppBar. I need the textfield to appear in the center of the screen with an eventual overlay proposing suggestions.

Is there anyway to use the ShowSearch in that objective ? Could I modify the class a certain way to achieve that ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an abundance of semi-useful tutorials and half-complete libraries, but no good built-in way to do search in Flutter...

That said, have a look at `search.dart` (where `showSearch()` and `SearchDelegate` are defined): The `build()` method hardcodes the building of a dedicated search page, including scaffold, appBar and body.

If you think it's worth it, you can simply copy the code from this file and create your own custom search, e.g. rename to `showCustomSearch()` and `CustomSearchDelegate` and take it from there.